# looking for a fast way to copy a template to a KVM guest

Tags: kvm-virtualization, template

My KVM guests each has a logical volume on the host to be the entire virtual disk. What will be a fast way to copy a template over to the guest's virtual disk? I tried to create a lzop compressed file first, then uncompress the file on the virtual disk. It costs 230 seconds to copy a 10GB template. But only 1GB of the 10GB template is occupied by a pre-installed OS. Any faster way to do this?

Comment: Use LVM snapshots?

Answer (score 0):

Partimag would probably work for what you're doing.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Uhh, what? There are no links in my answer.